# Database Class Instance, Fields, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im new to C# and Entity Framework and I have a question about fields and initialization of a database class.

I have received some code in a program from my teacher that has a connection to a MySQL database through Entity Framework.

So far we have seen examples where inside methods for adding stuff to the database you first create an instance of it. An example of what we have seen so far:

```
using (var db = new p4_databaseEntities())
        {
            cp_car carEntity = new cp_car();
            carEntity.make = car.make;
            carEntity.model = car.model;
            carEntity.year = car.year;

            db.cp_car.Add(carEntity); // 
            db.SaveChanges();

            MessageBox.Show("A Car has been added");

        } 
        this.Close();
```

cp_car is a table in the database and a class in the program. 
db is the current instance of the database.

Now, in the code I have received, this is not done this way. Its done in a different matter. Btw the program is a windows forms.

In the first form window, inside the constructor, he has created a new instance of the database and he calls upon a method called init
from the another class called LinqQueries. The code for that:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        p4_databaseEntities db = new p4_databaseEntities(); 
        LinqQueries.Init(db); 

        this.CenterToScreen();
    }
```

How the LinqQueries class looks:

```
     private static p4_databaseEntities _db; 

    public static void Init(p4_databaseEntities db) 
    {
        _db = db;
    }
```

As I understand he created a new instance of the database in the constructor, where he also called on the init method. This method then defined the db object as _db. Now every single method he makes for adding or removing data from the database he is using _db and not db.

My question is does this mean that the init method assigns the static field of type p4_databaseEntities (name of database class) as an object? Is the value of the _db then an object? Is it a reference to an object? And also i noticed he uses the same field over and over again when making changes to the database which led me to believe it may be an active object that doesn’t die through out the programs lifespan?

If anyone could clarify this It would be greatly appreciated. Excuse any errors or wrong statements I have made please correct me if im wrong in any way. Im new to C# and Entity Framework.

Thanks beforehand

Comment: Who wrote that code? Could you ask the author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are a bit inaccurate in your descriptions. This attributes to your confusion.

A DbContext is not a database, it represents the connection to the database. If you construct a DbContext object, you get access to the tables in the database via the Entities described in the DbSet.

Although it seems that a DbSet represents a table in the database, it does not. For instance an entity that you access via a DbSet can have an ICollection as member, which contains items that are not part of the table, but are items in a different table. Accessing the items in this ICollection causes an SQL Join to be performed, without you having to type the join

Hence a DbSet object in the DbConnection does not represent database table, it represents the access to the properties that can be accessed using the DbSet object, inclusive the properties of all objects in the database that are in tables that have a relation with the DbSet object.

Your first code with the using statement is the normal way entity framework should be used.

To hide the design of the database, quite often a separate class is introduced that is the only one that should use the DbContext. All users of the database should communicate using the seperate class.

This allows changing the internals of the database without having to change the code that uses the database.

This is what probably was meant as the purpose of the LinqQueries class. Instead of calling functions of the DbContext directly, users should call the (probably static) functions of LinqQueries. This way the internal structure of the database can change without having to change the callers of the LinqQueries functions.

What in fact is happening is that LinqQueries is meant to communicate with only one DbContext. LinqQueries does not decide which DbContext is used. Proper functioning depends heavily on exactly one user of LinqQueries who should create a DbContext and Init LinqQueries. This one user should also know when no one needs the LinqQueries anymore, because he has to Dispose() the DbContext.

This design if fairly error prone. Supposing the designer makes very grood products, his products will be used by a lot of users (meaning software, not operators). How do you assert that exactly one user will call the Init function?

If you really want that all users use the same Dbcontext, why not let the constructor of LinqQueries create this DbContext. In fact the design is similar to the singleton design pattern, so why not create LinqQueries as a singleton.

The limitation that all users of LinqQuery should use the same one and only DbContext limits the use of the LinqQuery class unnecessarily.

If users of the LinqQuery class could pass a DbContext to the constructor, then users could decide which database should be used by this particular LinqQueries object. This is quite handy when creating unit tests: instead of using the original database, the testable code could be used with a database with specific test values.

All in all the goal of the designer is unclear. IMHO it is a bad design and you are right that it is not clear what happens.

```
class LinqQueries
{
    // default constructor: use the default DbContext
    public LinqQueries()
    {
        this.DbContext = new p4_databaseEntities();
    }

    // special constructor: user provided dbContext
    public LinqQueries(p4_databaseEntities dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    private readonly p4_databaseEntities dbContext;

    public IEnumerable<...> GetMyElements(...)
    {
         return this.dbContext....;
    }
}
```

This way, every creator of the LinqQueries would exactly know what to do either  use the default p4_databaseEntities or create your own Dbcontext and dispose it when not needed anymore

```
using (var mydbContext = new p4_databaseEntities())
{
    LinqQueries linqQueries = new LinqQueries(myDbContext);
    // note that this constructor is very lightWeight!

    var result = linqQueries.MyQuery(...);
}
```

This method is really safe. Any errors made by me, does not influence the code of any other user of the LinqQuery class.

Comment: thanks very much for your broad reflection and error spotting! I will def talk to the author of the code to understand what is happening really